# Show a webpage based on date and time criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve a solution based on time and date input.

Given a simple input such as:

```
<input id="dateTime" type="datetime-local" onclick="redirect()">
```

What I am trying to figure out is how do I redirect to one website if the given date and time is beyond 3 days and after 2:00pm CST and redirect to another website if the given date and time is less than 3 days and before 2:00pm CST, for example. How would I achieve this?

Comment: you use a form or a page redirect with the datetime as a param

Comment: Could you give me an example of the implementation?

Comment: you don't know how to create a form?

Comment: or you don't know how to assign a url to the window.location variable?

Comment: @madalinivascu OP wants to have a datepicker on their site; when the date is three days before the current date, redirect to a website. If the entered date is three days after the current date, redirect to another website.

Comment: I don't know how to implement the JavaScript that drives the rule behind what I am trying to achieve. Basically, if (date & time > 3 days & 2pm) do this, else, if (date & time < 3 days & 2pm), do that.

Comment: so you don't know how to work with dates, i suggest you use moment.js

Comment: Great, could you point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need Javascript and you can redirect to any page you wish with the following:

```
JavaScript Redirect Methods

  window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";

  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

  window.location.assign("http://stackoverflow.com");

  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

What you'll have to do in this instance is a statment declaring the time inputted by the user and where you want them to be located. The code will be something along the lines of this:

```
if (time() < strtotime("06/20/2018  5:00PM"))
{
    //redirect to current
    header("Location : http://website.com/current");
    exit;
}
    elseif(time() > strtotime("06/20/2018  1:00PM")){

    //redirect to new
    header("Location : http://website.com/new");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Could you help me with the implementation of the JavaScript that drives the rule behind what I am trying to achieve. Basically, if (date & time > 3 days & 2pm) do this, else, if (date & time < 3 days & 2pm), do that.

Comment: Will add to my answer, one sec. :)

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try :)

Comment: Is that PHP? strtotime I don't think is Javascript